# How to use PostbackURL to display values in an html table

Tags: php, asp.net, postback

I'm setting up an HTML web page that has a table in it.
The table would be populated with data coming from a `postbackurl` ping.

This is for a Centos 7.2 Server.
I have no knowledge regarding PostbackURL and how they work

In theory, what I want to achieve (based on previous works with tables and data)
(Given that the `postbackurl` is `domain.com/?transaction_id=??&customer_id=???`) 
a Service Pings:

`the PostbackURL given` -->
`Data is somehow stored in a database` -->
`a Web Page displays said Data`

Comment: Welcome to [so], B. Johnson! What have you tried? Please post an [mcve].

Comment: Hey Ethan, sadly I've tried nothing so far since i really have no idea where to start, if you could point me to the right direction, that will be highly appreciated. I do have some knowledge regarding html, php, mysql interaction but it's very limited, very beginner stuff.

Comment: You could search [so] or [Google](https://google.com) for it, or you could give us your best try and give us some of your HTML (but Minimal and Complete, so only the table) We kind of don't just give you code so we need a bit more and you might get an answer (The first point in [ask] tells you that you need research).